# Or statement & conditions dictating execution of one of two or three for loops

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

Here is my data within Cells E1:G14

```
Issue Name                      Ticker
F/c 90day euro$ futr  dec15  Edz5 xcme
F/c h-shares idx fut  jul15     Hcn5 xhkf
F/c mini msci emg mkt sep15     Mesu5ifus
F/c s&p/tsx 60 ix fut sep15     Ptu5 xmod
F/c russell 2000 mini sep15     Rtau5ifus
F/c swiss mkt ix futr sep15     Smu5 xeur
F/c us 10yr note(cbt) sep15     Tyu5 xcbt
F/c euro buxl 30y bnd sep15     Ubu5 xeur
F/c euro stoxx 50     sep15     Vgu5 xeur
F/c us ultra bond(cbt sep15     Wnu5 xcbt
F/c gasoline rbob fut sep15     Xbu5 xnym
F/c aust 10yr bond fut sep 15   Xmu5 xsfe
F/c ftse 100 idx fut  sep15     Z u5 ifll
```

And my code as of right now:

```
Sub copy_paste()

Worksheets(1).Activate
Dim ch As Long
Dim c As Variant
Dim d As Variant
Dim v As Range
Dim w As Range
Dim brow As Long
Dim crow As Long
Dim cc As Variant

Set w = Sheets(1).Range("E:E")
brow = w(w.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set w = Range(w(2), w(brow))

Set v = Sheets(1).Range("G:G")
brow = v(v.Cells.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set v = Range(v(2), v(brow))

    For Each d In w
        d = d.Text
        If InStr(1, d, "mini") Then
                For Each c In v
                bbv1 = " QR "
                bbv2 = " HCPI "
                c = Mid(c, 1, 5) & " <INDEX>" & bbv2 '& c.Offset(0, 3)
                Debug.Print (c)
            Next c
        End If
Next d
End Sub
```

My out put from this half of my code is as follows:

```
Edz5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Hcn5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Mesu5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Ptu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Rtau5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Smu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Tyu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Ubu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Vgu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Wnu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Xbu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Xmu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Z u5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Edz5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Hcn5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Mesu5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Ptu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Rtau5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Smu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Tyu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Ubu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Vgu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Wnu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Xbu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Xmu5  <INDEX> HCPI 
Z u5  <INDEX> HCPI
```

The procedure cycles through each Issue name, two of which meet the `mini` criteria and thus are printed to the immediate console in the desired format. Now I would like to execute another for loop identical to the one above except handling a different criteria: `ix` instead of `mini` and if any Issue name meets neither of these criteria I would like an `Elseif` statement to handle the remaining issue names.

```
If InStr(1, d, "ix") Then
    For Each c In v
        bbv1 = " QR "
        bbv2 = " HCPI "
        c = Mid(c, 1, 4) & " <INDEX>" & bbv2 & c.Offset(0, 3)
        Debug.Print (c)
        Next c
     End If

Elseif
            For Each c In v
            'ch = DDEInitiate("winblp", "bbk")
                bbv1 = " QR "
                bbv2 = " HCPI "
                c = Mid(c, 1, 5) & " <INDEX>" & bbv2 '& c.Offset(0, 3)
                Debug.Print (c)
            Next c
        End If
`The syntax may be wrong on the Elseif
```

Ergo any commodity future which does not represent and index should be printed as `Xbu5 <CMDTY> HCPI` how ever I have not been able to figure out how to switch for loops on these conditions. How could I incorporate an OR condition within the If `InStr()` method and eliminate one of the first two for loops?

The final desired results should be: (Please note the `mini` Indices have a `c = Mid(c, 1, 5)` condition)

```
Edz5 <CMDTY> HCPI 
Hcn5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Mesu5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Ptu5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Rtau5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Smu5 <INDEX> HCPI 
Tyu5 <CMDTY> HCPI 
Ubu5 <CMDTY> HCPI 
Vgu5 <CMDTY> HCPI 
Wnu5 <CMDTY> HCPI 
Xbu5 <CMDTY> HCPI 
Xmu5 <CMDTY> HCPI 
Z u5 <CMDTY> HCPI
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow exactly, but I think you can resolve this by putting your `Instr` test *inside* the loop and doing conditional assignment to `c`, rather than trying to "switch" loops or otherwise build three different loops.

```
For Each d In w
    d = d.Text

    For Each c In v
        bbv1 = " QR "
        bbv2 = " HCPI "
        If InStr(1, d, "mini") Then
            c = Mid(c, 1, 5) & " <INDEX>" & bbv2 '& c.Offset(0, 3)
        ElseIf Instr(1, d, "ix") Then
            c = Mid(c, 1, 4) & " <INDEX>" & bbv2 & c.Offset(0, 3)
        Else
            c = Mid(c, 1, 5) & " <INDEX>" & bbv2
        End If
        Debug.Print (c)
    Next c

Next d
```

Comment: The output is more than expected

Comment: You're welcome?  (I honestly have no idea how to interpret your comment...)

Comment: I think I need to put a `next c` after each if statement, only

Comment: Each `c` is only evaluated against one part of the if/elseif/else block. They are mutually exclusive logical flow statements.

Comment: Only 13 lines of output are needed each ticker should be only be printed once with its appropriate if condition

Comment: The third if else statement should have the CMDTY value and this the output should represent the last thirteen lines in the op

Comment: After each `c = Mid...` statement put an `Exit For`? Although without trying it I don't know if that's going to change anything...

Comment: How could I get the output to equal ` Edz5 <CMDTY> HCPI Hcn5 <INDEX> HCPI Mesu5 <INDEX> HCPI Ptu5 <INDEX> HCPI Rtau5 <INDEX> HCPI Smu5 <INDEX> HCPI Tyu5 <CMDTY> HCPI Ubu5 <CMDTY> HCPI Vgu5 <CMDTY> HCPI Wnu5 <CMDTY> HCPI Xbu5 <CMDTY> HCPI Xmu5 <CMDTY> HCPI Z u5 <CMDTY> HCPI ` nothing more nothing less?